# Boolean determined by whether or not an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, exception, boolean

I'm trying to check object values surrounding a certain index an array. For example, in a 5 X 5 array, row 3 column 3 is selected, then the code will check:

1 1 1 1 1

1 **1 1 1** 1

1 **1 s 1** 1

1 **1 1 1** 1

1 1 1 1 1

where s is the selected value in the array and bolded 1's are the values the code checks for.

In certain edge cases, such as the top left 1, ArrayOutOfBoundsExceptions can be thrown. 
Is it possible to write code in a way such that:

```
while(anExceptionIsNotThrown):
   check surrounding value
```

Comment: That's the wrong way to write code. Exceptions should be for exceptional situations. You know the array has bounds, so check them before you try to access it, rather than going into slow exception-winding mode for no good reason every time you get near the edge.

Comment: The only way to handle exceptions in java if the need arises is by using the try catch blocks

Comment: There's no code, so there's zero way to provide meaningful assistance. It sounds like you're using exceptions inappropriately--relying on them instead of simply using the length. Please see the FAQ regarding how to ask questions--this question is incomplete as asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean failed = false;
while (!failed){
    try{
        //code that maybe throws an exception
    } catch (ArrayOutOfBoundsException e){
        failed = true;
    }
}
```

If the Exception is thrown, the failed flag will be set to true, thus indicating the while loop to stop.
Another solution using the `break` statement:

```
while (true){
    try{
        //code that maybe throws an exception
    } catch (ArrayOutOfBoundsException e){
        break;
    }
}
```

However: `while (true)` is never a good idea so replace it with your own condition for the three rows/columns (also in the first examle using `&&`).

While my solutions will work, I totally agree with Joseph Sible's comment that you should rather check your array bounds than waiting for an exception to be thrown